# Calculation of scattering parameter

Tags: emc, scattering

I am not able to calculate the scattering matrix of a pi-circuit although I have calculated its Y matrix. The needed scattering matrix is referred to 50Ω.

Could someone help me on calculating the scattering matrix?

I tried to deduct the S50 matrix using the attached picture https://ibb.co/G7JZBGY

however, I got at the end 2 non linear equations for 2 unknown variables

Comment: What have you tried (show your calculations) and where did you not get what you expected?

Comment: How are you trying to do it? Are you using the equations on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admittance_parameters) page?

Comment: I am using this formula (https://ibb.co/G7JZBGY) and I am having a circle equation as a solution